# How to make npm run build on local machine with help of github actions?

Tags: linux, git, github, vps, github-actions

I have a Nuxt Js application on my ubuntu server. I use  my terminal to enter server and run commands on my server. I can't run command "npm run build" because my VPS has low memory and build command freezes.So I decided to make build on my PC, copy built folder to VPS and then run application.

**What should I write in github actions to perform those steps?**

-npm run build

-copy built folder from my machine to VPS using ssh(or password, it doesn't matter) to specific folder on VPS

What I did last time and it worked for me:

```
name: Deployment Setup

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  job-one:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Testing VPS connection and deploy project
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: 114.12.587.105
          port: 1234
          username: new-user
          key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY}}
          uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
          script: |
            cd /home/kentforth/webapps/myapp
            git pull
            npm install --production
            quasar build
            sudo service nginx restart
```

**EDIT:**
Here is my deploy.yml file:

```
name: 'test my project'
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x, 14.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm run build
```

Here is What I get in github actions:
[image: error]

It seems github actions try to find path /home/runner/work/my project name
But I do not have such directory

How can specify I the folder on my local machine where "npm run build" command should run?

Comment: What seems to be the problem now? Can you link the result of running this action?